# Customized conditional assertion error message in Clojure?

Tags: clojure

Suppose I want alert the user the input type is wrong, for example

```
(defn my-sqrt [x] {:pre [(not (neg? x))]}        (Math/sqrt x))
```

Is it possible to issue a message  "Positive number only.", instead of something like assert failed?

Answer (score 4):

You can do this using [dire](https://github.com/MichaelDrogalis/dire). You should look at its support for [preconditions](https://github.com/MichaelDrogalis/dire#preconditions).

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to rely on external libraries, clojure's `(assert)` supports an optional message.

The drawbacks are, you'll lose the readability of a `:pre` and will have to save the result in an intermediate variable for a `:post` check (or wrap it up in some macro magic).

Simple example:

```
(defn mysqrt [x]
  ;; preconditions
  (assert (pos? x) "Positive numbers only")
  (let [y (Math/sqrt x)]
    ;; postconditions
    (assert (number? y) "Some strange error happened")
    y))
```